# Add Line Break In PHP Table

Tags: php, line-breaks

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I'm using the code below to create a table on my web page.

```
   <table id="report" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
              <th width="150"></th>
          <th width="140"><div align="left">Location Name</div></th>
          <th width="398"><div align="left">Address</div></th>
              <th width="124"><div align="center">Finds Made</div></th>
              <th width="280"></th>
              <th width="101"></th>
              <th width="166"></th>
              <th width="90"></th>
        </tr>
        <?php

                        echo "<tr>
                                <td><div><a href='delete.php?locid=$lid'>Delete Location</a></div></td> 
                                <td><div align='left'>$lname</div></td>
                                <td><div align='left'>$laddress</div></td>
                                <td><div align='center'>$findscount</div></td>
                                <td><div><a href='viewlocation.php?locid=$lid'>View/Amend Location Details</a></div></td>  
                                <td><div><a href='addfinds.php?locid=$lid'>Add Finds</a></div></td> 
                                <td><div><a href='addfinds.php?locid=$lid'>Add Find Images</a></div></td>
                                <td><div><a href='finddetails.php?locid=$lid'>View Finds</a></div></td> 
                            </tr>";
                            echo "<th colspan=\"8\"><hr width=\"100%\"></th>";
```

What I'm trying to do and having problems with is to create a line break between each row of data, I'd like to place it before this line of my code: `echo "<th colspan=\"8\"><hr width=\"100%\"></th>";`

I've tried using `"\n"`, `echo "\n"`, `"<br />"` to name but a few, but I can't seem to get this to work.

I just wondered whether someone may be able to look at this please and let me know where I'm going wrong.

Many thanks and regards

Comment: you can try echo "<tr><td rowspan=8>$nbsp;</td></tr>";

Comment: Hi @ZuberSurya, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post. I've tried the code and unfortunately it doesn't work and I receive a CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING error.Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <tr><th colspan="8"><br/><hr width="100%"></th><tr>
```

Comment: i think also can be do it by css, by padding top(replace <br/>) and border-bottom (replace <hr/>), height and display block

Answer (score 0):

Your `<th>` also needs a wrapping `<tr>`. Then add this to your css

```
th[colspan=8] { margin-top: 1em; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it like this:

```
echo "<th colspan=\"8\"><hr width=\"100%\"></th>\r\n" .
     "<td></td>" .
```

...and so on.

Comment: I usually never echo or print html tags. I always close the PHP scripting tag `?>` and re-open it after the html. You can then output values like `<?=$lname?>`, `<?php print($lname); ?>` or `<?php echo $lname; ?>`. And if it's a more complex project, use a template engine like Smarty.

Comment: Hi @Jan Petzold, thnak you for taking the time to reply ro my post. I've added the cod to my post, and, although i'mm not receiving any error, the line break is not being created. Kind regards